# Magento 2: file_get_content() is not working on server

Tags: magento2, php

I have used `file_get_content()` in my Magento 2 and it response data in my local system, but once I upload file to server it returns empty data

I also check `allow_url_fopen=on` and my PHP version is **7.2** for both local as well as server

Does anyone have an idea what is the exact problem or any other alternative?